# EF saving entity references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have the following situation.

I'm building a course management MVC site where I have courses but also course iterations I call them as it happens sometime that a new student will join just for one iteration.

I have a model courseIterations which possess a ICollection of students. When starting the course I want to generate the next nine iterations with default students which subscribed to the course. The problem I have is that when I list the iterations the students where not saved. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better approach in general?

```
public class CourseIteration : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
}
```

My attempt to fill

```
private void FillIterations(Course course, int coursePeriod)
    {
        var defaultStudents = _studentRepository.GetAllByCourse(course.CourseID).ToList(); // load the existing Items

        course.Iterations = new List<CourseIteration>();

        for (int i = 0; i < coursePeriod; i++)
        {
            var item = new CourseIteration
            {
                Course = course,
                Date = course.StartDate.AddDays(i * 7),
                Instructors = course.Instructors,
                Students = new List<Student>()
            };

            foreach (var student in defaultStudents)
            {
                item.Students.Add(student);
            }
            _courseIterationRepository.Add(item);

            course.Iterations.Add(item);

            _courseIterationRepository.Save();

            _courseRepository.Save();
        }
    }
```

I use a Generic Repository
        public abstract class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository
      where T : BaseEntity
    {
        protected DbContext _entities;
        protected readonly IDbSet _dbset;

```
    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _entities = context;
        _dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbset.AsEnumerable<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> query = _dbset.Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
        return query;
    }

    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual T Attach(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Attach(entity);
    }

    public virtual T Delete(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Save();
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Custom Save function could be the problem?

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.Entity is IAuditableEntity
                && (x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added || x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
        {
            IAuditableEntity entity = entry.Entity as IAuditableEntity;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                string identityName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entity.CreatedBy = identityName;
                    entity.CreatedDate = now;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                }

                entity.UpdatedBy = identityName;
                entity.UpdatedDate = now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your repositories? Are they sharing the same `DbContext`? Can't find anything wrong here...

Comment: Maybe  `defaultStudents` is empty list?

Comment: No defaultStudents is fine. Also the whole courseitteration looks good before saving.

Comment: The problem could lie here. I copied this code. it seams to not detect that this entities have changed..

Comment: Could it be a mapping problem for many to many relationship ?

Comment: Couldn't find any tried a lot of different approaches